# Loop that extracts XML nodes into table under the corresponding headers

Tags: excel, xml, vba, foreach

I read an XML document to collect user logon times.

> <UserName="Jenny" Monday="7:00" Tuesday="7:30" Wednesday="0" Thursday="7:10" Friday="7:25" Saturday="6:00" Sunday="0"/><UserName="Simon" Monday="8:20" Tuesday="7:45" Wednesday="7:45" Thursday="7:10" Friday="7:25" Saturday="7:00" Sunday="0"/><UserName="Jenny" Monday="8:00" Tuesday="8:30" Wednesday="8:00" Thursday="7:10" Friday="7:25" Saturday="0" Sunday="0"/>Chris

I can get and paste info into a table on an Excel spreadsheet one by one.

```vb
Dim pTeamTimes As New XMLdoc  
Dim objPlan As IXMLDOMElement
        
'build file path
strTeamXMLPath = "C:\Users\Public\Libraries\Times" & ".xml"
        
'load document
objPlan .LoadDocument strTeamXMLPath , "TeamTimes"
                          
For Each objPlan In pTeamTimes.Root.ChildNodes 
    
    .Cells(intRow, 13) = User
    .Cells(intRow, 14) = objPlan .getAttribute("Monday")
    .Cells(intRow, 15) = objPlan .Attributes.getNamedItem("Tuesday").Text
    .Cells(intRow, 16) = objPlan .Attributes.getNamedItem("Wednesday").Text
    .Cells(intRow, 17) = objPlan .Attributes.getNamedItem("Thursday").Text
    .Cells(intRow, 18) = objPlan .Attributes.getNamedItem("Friday").Text
    .Cells(intRow, 19) = objPlan .Attributes.getNamedItem("Saturday").Text
    .Cells(intRow, 20) = objPlan .Attributes.getNamedItem("Sunday").Text
    intRow = intRow + 1
                              
Next objPlan
```

This pastes the data into a table with the user name on the left and the times to the right row by row (see below).

```
User|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday
```

Is there a way to loop through the file and extract the appropriate data for the appropriate header?

I also played with `.getAttribute("Monday")` and `.Attributes.getNamedItem("Tuesday").Text`

Is there a major difference in using each of these methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Streamlining display of xml node attributes (array approach)**

Your **XML** file snippet's syntax isn't correct. Each node has to show its node name after the opening bracket `<SomeNode ...>`, but this nodename cannot be followed immediately by an equals character `=` indicating always a following attribute assignment.

Therefore I built a wellformed xml structure to be able to illustrate a working [MCV Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) choosing to ("re")name the individual nodes `<User ...>` followed by `UserName` and weekday attributes (`Monday="7:00" Tuesday="" ...`).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AllUsers>
  <Team>
    <User UserName="Jenny" Monday="7:00" Tuesday="7:30" Wednesday="0" Thursday="7:10" Friday="7:25" Saturday="6:00" Sunday="0"/>
    <User UserName="Simon" Monday="8:20" Tuesday="7:45" Wednesday="7:45" Thursday="7:10" Friday="7:25" Saturday="7:00" Sunday="0"/>
    <User UserName="Jenny2" Monday="8:00" Tuesday="8:30" Wednesday="8:00" Thursday="7:10" Friday="7:25" Saturday="0" Sunday="0"/>
  </Team>
</AllUsers>
```

**Example code**

Based on this assumed example structure (loaded here via `.LoadXML`), I demonstrate how to streamline code getting attributes via a **NodeList** loop based on the following xml content.

In order to allow a quickly reproducible example, I didn't refer to an external file via `.Load`, but to a pure string content (received by help function `getContent()`) loaded via `.LoadXML`. Of course loading an external file needs the following syntax: `xDoc.Load strTeamXMLPath`. - Btw several parts of the original code aren't clear, e.g. I don't know what's behind `.LoadDocument`

```
Sub GetAttributes()
    Dim xdoc  As MSXML2.DOMDocument60       ' early binding needs reference to Microsoft 'XML, v6.0'
    Set xdoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    
    If xdoc.LoadXML(getContent()) Then
        Dim users As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
        Set users = xdoc.SelectNodes("//Team/User")     ' nodelist is zero-based
        ReDim tmp(1 To users.Length, 1 To 8)
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To users.Length
            Dim j As Long
            For j = 1 To users(i - 1).Attributes.Length
                'assign to 1-based 2-dim tmp array
                '(whereas users nodelist incl. node attributes list are zero-based!)
                tmp(i, j) = users(i - 1).Attributes(j - 1).Text
                'Debug.Print i & "." & j, tmp(i, j)      ' optional display in VB Editor's immediate window
            Next
            Debug.Print i, Join(Application.Index(tmp, i, 0), "|")
        Next i
    Else    ' XML Parse Error
        Debug.Print getParseError(xdoc)
    End If
    ' write tmp to any target
    With Sheet1                               ' << change to your project's sheet Code(Name)
'        'a) write captions starting from cell M1 (optional)
'        For i = 1 To UBound(tmp, 2)
'            .Range("M1").Offset(0, i - 1) = users(0).Attributes(i - 1).BaseName
'        Next i
        'write tmp results
        .Range("M2").Resize(UBound(tmp, 1), UBound(tmp, 2)) = tmp
    End With
    End Sub
```

Additionaly you could test other syntax, e.g. for the 1st user (Jenny) to get the `Monday` attribute:

```
    Debug.Print users(0).Attributes.getNamedItem("Monday").BaseName                ' "Monday"
    Debug.Print users(0).Attributes.getNamedItem("Monday").Text                    ' 7:00
    Debug.Print xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Team/User[1]/@Monday").Text ' 7:00
```

**Help functions**

Function `getContent()` gets an assumed minimal, but wellformed xml string content as described above replacing the unknown structure of OP's external file content.

```
Function getContent() As String
Dim tmp As String
tmp = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" & vbNewLine
tmp = tmp & "<AllUsers>" & vbNewLine & "  <Team>" & vbNewLine & _
vbTab & "<User UserName=""Jenny"" Monday=""7:00"" Tuesday=""7:30"" Wednesday=""0"" Thursday=""7:10"" Friday=""7:25"" Saturday=""6:00"" Sunday=""0""/>" & vbNewLine & _
vbTab & "<User UserName=""Simon"" Monday=""8:20"" Tuesday=""7:45"" Wednesday=""7:45"" Thursday=""7:10"" Friday=""7:25"" Saturday=""7:00"" Sunday=""0""/>" & vbNewLine & _
vbTab & "<User UserName=""Jenny2"" Monday=""8:00"" Tuesday=""8:30"" Wednesday=""8:00"" Thursday=""7:10"" Friday=""7:25"" Saturday=""0"" Sunday=""0""/>" & vbNewLine & _
"  </Team>" & vbNewLine & "</AllUsers>"
getContent = tmp
Debug.Print getContent
End Function
```

```
Function getParseError(xdoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60) As String
        Dim xPE As MSXML2.IXMLDOMParseError
        Set xPE = xdoc.parseError
        With xPE
            getParseError = "Load Error " & .ErrorCode & " XML File " & vbCrLf & _
                  Replace(.Url, "file:///", "") & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                  xPE.reason & _
                  "Source Text: " & .srcText & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                  "Line No:    " & .Line & vbCrLf & _
                  "Line Pos:  " & .linepos & vbCrLf & _
                  "File Pos:  " & .filepos & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        End With
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, that works great thank you. sorry with OP I was trying to give more of an outline and had missed out bit i didnt think were relevant (but possibly were).